# ~ meaning of this symbol when used in the context f~g?

Tags: real-analysis

Currently studying a chapter on improper integrals in a real analysis book and the following is stated:"f~g means that $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$$
I am wondering what is the ~ actually called?

Comment: Generally speaking ~ is reserved for an equivalence relation.

Comment: The symbol $\sim$ is called a tilde

Comment: The symbol called a "tilde", but in a sentence, you would say that "$f$ is **asymptotically equivalent** to $g$"

Answer (score 1):

The tilde symbol $\sim$ is a general symbol used in mathematics to denote a binary relation between objects. In this particular context, it means "on the order of" or "asymptotically equal to". It [belongs to a family of Bachmann-Landau notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations), and is related to Big O notation.